# Set up my MapView; how do I add more than one annotation?

Tags: annotations, mkmapview, mapkit

I've created a MapView in my app that zooms into the user's current location, and it works perfectly. See my code below:

**.h file**

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController  <MKMapViewDelegate> 

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

**.m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidUnload];

    [mapView setMapType:MKMapTypeStandard];
    [mapView setZoomEnabled:YES];
    [mapView setScrollEnabled:YES];



    self.mapView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation

{
    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"You Are Here";
point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

This code places an annotation where the user's current location is. However from here, I want to add multiple annotations (so that users can see key locations around them). What code do I need to add/change in order to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mapkit multiple annotation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894790/mapkit-multiple-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done many, many different ways. It depends on your data source and needs

Here's a way to add two

```
MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
point.title = @"You Are Here";
point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point];


MKPointAnnotation *point2 = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
point2.coordinate = aDifferentCoordinate;
point2.title = @"You Are Here";
point2.subtitle = @"Your current location";

[self.mapView addAnnotation:point2];
```

Here's a way to add a thousand at the same point

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"You Are Here";
    point.subtitle = @"Your current location";

   [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Comment: Hi Craig, this is super helpful; thank you! I'm not sure if you know the answer to this, but what would the code look like if I want to call 20+ annotations (longitude/latitude points) from a MySQL database  and display them on the MapView? (I've already made the connection to the SQL database, created the PHP file that spits out the coordinates in JSON, etc)

Comment: Well at that point the MySQL is irrelevant, what you want to do is ask a new question and tag it as JSON and objective-C, then you'll find someone with that sort of knowledge.